# How to put these lines into a single line?

Tags: vba

How to put these lines into a single line ?

1,2,3,4......26
B2,C2,D2,.......Z2

```
Sheets("1").Range("B2:B300").Copy Sheets("Result").Range("B2")
Sheets("2").Range("B2:B300").Copy Sheets("Result").Range("C2")
Sheets("3").Range("B2:B300").Copy Sheets("Result").Range("D2")
Sheets("4").Range("B2:B300").Copy Sheets("Result").Range("E2")
Sheets("5").Range("B2:B300").Copy Sheets("Result").Range("F2")
.
.
.
Sheets("25").Range("B2:B300").Copy Sheets("Result").Range("Y2")
Sheets("26").Range("B2:B300").Copy Sheets("Result").Range("Z2")
```

Comment: What do you mean a single line? A single row?

Comment: Please add some more detail as to what you want.  They say a picture is worth 1000 words, so a screen-shot example may help if it's hard to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Do a for loop:

```
For x = 1 to 26
    Sheets(Cstr(x)).Range("B2:B300").Copy Sheets("Result").Cells(2,x+1)
next x
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The above loop worked as I expected.

Comment: @M.GOW Glad to help please mark as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following method helps to you

```
Sub GetCopyOfColumnB()
Dim ws  As Worksheet
Dim resultPageName As String
Dim isTherePage As Boolean
Dim i As Integer


resultPageName = "Result"
isTherePage = False

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name = resultPageName Then
        isTherePage = True
    End If
Next
If isTherePage = False Then

    Worksheets.Add After:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

    Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = resultPageName
End If
i = 1
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> resultPageName Then
        ws.Range("B2:B300").Copy Sheets("Result").Cells(2, i)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```